# Event profile(s) field/table

Tags: civievent, profile

In what table are the online event registration profiles stored? They don't appear to be in civicrm_event where I would expect to find their profile IDs.
Thanks, Karen

Answer (score 1):

Profiles are stored in **civicrm_uf_group** and the fields are in **civicrm_uf_field**. Search the column **uf_group_type** in civicrm_uf_group to see what the profile is used for or just lookup a particular profile id.

To search by an event id you will also need to look in **civicrm_uf_join** and use something like:

`SELECT group_id where module = 'CiviEvent' AND entity_id = {my_event_id}`